# Find the square root of the number without using any built-in function?

Tags: java, binary-search

I am working on below problem:

> Given an integer, how do you find the square root of the number
>   without using any built-in function?

```
  private static double computeSquareRootBinarySearch(double x, double precision) {
    double start = 0;
    double end = x / 2 + 1;
    double mid = (start + ((end - start) / 2));
    double prevMid = 0;
    double diff = Math.abs(mid - prevMid);

    while ((mid * mid != x) && (diff > precision)) {
      if (mid * mid > x) {
        end = mid;
      } else {
        start = mid;
      }
      prevMid = mid;
      mid = (start + end) / 2;
      diff = Math.abs(mid - prevMid);
    }
    return mid;
  }
```

I came up with above binary search algo but wanted to see if there is any optimization I can do in above algorithm?

Comment: If you can use `Math.abs()`, then why not also use `Math.sqrt()`?

Comment: Agree with @200_success, try to compute the `Abs(...)` by yourself. Otherwise, why theses operations in the `mid` and `diff` initialization? And, it's not stated that the result must be the closest *greater* possible. So, why `+ 1` in the `end` init?

Comment: a really efficent way to calculate approximations would be to use the Secant method (see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secant_method)

Answer (score 2):

- It is unlikely that `mid * mid` would ever be equal to `x`, so the opportunistic `mid * mid != x` consumes more cycles than it may save. I recommend to drop it entirely.
- The convergence rate is not the best. Your algorithm adds (approximately) one bit of precision per iteration. Compare it to a classic Newton-Raphson, which *doubles* the amount of correct bits per iteration.
- As mentioned in the comment, *without using any built-in function* part of assignment rules out using `Math.abs`.
- You may want to check the input for correctness: both `x` and `precision` must be positive.

Comment: mid*mid can be x ..Eg. 2*2=4